# SSL client - when is the certificate needed?

Tags: java, ssl, connection

I have this:

```
    SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("www.verisign.com", 443);
```

This is failing on the 2nd line with a "Connection refused" error.

Now, would I have to install verisign's certificate in my trust store before I can even do the above?  I was under the impression that I could connect to an SSL server and execute getPeerCertificates() to get the certificates.  Is this not what our browsers do?  Otherwise how would they know which signing authority to use?

(Obviously I'm using Verisign as an example.  My real URL is far too fugly to use here...)

Comment: I have to wonder if I'm getting burned by a firewall or something. I can't even do: URL url = new URL("www.google.com"); HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); and then read from con.getInputStream()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused means nothing was listening at the target host:port, or a firewall got in the way. This is logically and temporally prior to anything SSL does.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the remote service is actually up and running, and that you can connect to it?  Perhaps the "Connection refused" error is actually a refused connection.  :-)

Comment: @Tony Ennis: He said that that was not the site he's actually connecting to, but that he didn't want to reveal the URL.  Last sentence of the question :)

Comment: Yes, but I really did try the verisign web site.  It fails to connect to that one too. (Q: Does Verisign use a self-sighed certificate? lolz)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't need to install server's certificate on your computer explicitly. PKI works in the way that your system should be able to validate server's certificate without any prior knowledge about it. However this will work only when your server's certificate has it's roots in on of the "known CAs", i.e. certificate authorities, whose root or other certificates are already listed on the client system. If this is not the case (eg. you have a self-signed or some other custom certificate on the server), you really need to install the certificate on your client system before the mentioned classes can validate server certificate properly.

You can read [about certificates and how they are used in SSL here](http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1948.php).

Comment: _...your server's certificate has it's roots in on of the "known CAs...whose root or other certificates are already listed on the client system..._  So if the URL I want to connect to has a certificate signed by Verisign (for example) and Verisign is in my keystore, everything works behinds the scenes?

Comment: I've set the javax.net.ssl.trustStore and javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword environment variables, by the way.

Comment: @Tony Unfortunately I don't know how Java SSL classes verify certificates, i.e. whether Java Runtime maintains it's own list of trusted certificates. If it were .NET then the answer would be yes, you wouldn't need to do anything in regards to validation explicitly. With Java - I don't know.

Comment: I seem to recall something about $JAVA_ROOT/lib/security/cacerts being magical...

Comment: @Eugene and Tony: The root certificates for Java are stored in the trust store which by default points to the cacerts file alluded to by Tony. However, if you override this setting by for example setting the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property then you are on your own. The cacerts file contains a collection of pre-trusted roots comparable to what ships with Windows and Firefox.

Comment: My 1.6.0_22 java release had no lib/security directory and thus no cacerts file.  Just sayin'.  Verisign has a download page where you can get 14 of their certificates as well as those for thawte and another I can't recall right now.  I conject this is the same information that would be in the ideal cacerts file.